# need help for fixing selectonechoice error in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i have a selectonechoice with three values :A,B,C but i am getting following error on its change event:

```
<SimpleSelectOneRenderer> <_getSelectedIndex> Could not find selected item matching value "B" in RichSelectOneChoice[UIXEditableFacesBeanImpl, id=soc1]
```

My selectonechoice is configured as :

```
<af:selectOneChoice label="Condition Codes :" id="soc1"
                        valueChangeListener="#{myManageBean.onCondCodeChg}"
                        binding="#{myManageBean.propConditionCode}"
                        autoSubmit="true" valuePassThru="true"
                        unselectedLabel="Please Select"">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myManageBean.conditionCodes}" id="si1"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
```

Pls help!!!! where am i wrong ?

Comment: Can also post the method that returns the conditionCodes from the managed bean?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because even after the value is set, somehow the it's being overwritten by null value.

For me, the issue got solved by using `component.resetValue()` in the corresponding bean after the setter is called and value is set.

Answer (score 0):

use code bellow for you problem

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myManageBean.conditionCodes}" id="si1"/>
```

Comment: What?. Is it supposed to be a solution?

Comment: This is definitely not the solution to this issue.